# How to Make Metadata.Operation deploy work?

Tags: apex, deployment, metadata, metadata.operations

Did anyone tried to new Salesforce Summer 17 feature to deploy metadata records and layouts by Apex Code?

I tried to use this feature to update custom metadata record and it fails for me.
I just copied the examples from official documentation:

I have DeployCallback class implementation like [it is provided in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_Metadata_DeployCallback.htm#apex_Metadata_DeployCallback_methods) but it doesn't seem that this callback is even called

```
public class MyDeployCallback implements Metadata.DeployCallback {
    public void handleResult(Metadata.DeployResult result,
                             Metadata.DeployCallbackContext context) {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ result: ' + result );
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ context: ' + context );
        if (result.status == Metadata.DeployStatus.Succeeded) {
            // Deployment was successful
        } else {
            // Deployment was not successful
        }
    }
}
```

Also I copied [Deploy Metadata example from the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Metadata_Operations.htm#apex_class_Metadata_Operations)

```
public class CreateMetadata{
  public void updateAndDeployMetadata() {
    // Setup custom metadata to be created in the subscriber org.
    Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadata =  new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
    customMetadata.fullName = 'MetadataTypeName.MetadataRecordName';

    Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customField = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
    customField.field = 'customField__c';
    customField.value = 'New value';

    customMetadata.values.add(customField);

    Metadata.DeployContainer mdContainer = new Metadata.DeployContainer();
    mdContainer.addMetadata(customMetadata);

    // Setup deploy callback, MyDeployCallback implements
    // the Metadata.DeployCallback interface (code for
    // this class not shown in this example)
    MyDeployCallback callback = new MyDeployCallback();

    // Enqueue custom metadata deployment
    Id jobId = Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(mdContainer, callback);
      System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ jobId: ' + jobId );
  }
}

new CreateMetadata().updateAndDeployMetadata();
```

However, it doesn't seem to work.

I don't find the corresponding debug log for the Metadata Deploy Callback.

Also when I look at the deployment tab I see the following Fatal Error
[image: Fatal Error]
**Fatal Error
UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1021353307-20718 (1846919495)**

Below I see Component Errors message

***Component Errors***

Column
**Error Message
MetadataTypeName.MetadataRecordName Custom Metadata Record  0   0   Required fields are missing: [MasterLabel]**

I have even tried to modify my code and include the following line

```
customMetadata.MasterLabel = 'MetadataRecordName';
```

However, such code doesn't compile and throws error

***Variable does not exist: masterLabel***

When I try to modify this line to

```
customMetadata.label = 'MetadataRecordName';
```

It compiles but still gives error
[image: Fatal Error]

Strange, but the record gets updated or created in this case.

Does anyone know how to make Deploy Callback work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like we can't have DeployCallback defined in Anonymous Execution Window code.

If we define DeployCallback as separate class or an inner class of some class saved in the organization (not defined in Anonymous Execution Window) or if we pass second parameter as null then deployment succeeds
[image: Success]

Also looks like we don't have any option yet to have some action poller to poll async status.

**Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment** method returns Id starting with *0Af* prefix.

if we run this code to find out which SObject is related to this prefix

```
static string getTypeByPrefix(String prefix) {
Id some = prefix + '000000000000';
return some.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
}
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ v: ' + getTypeByPrefix('0Af'));
```

then it will return us **DeployRequest**.

However, if we try to run this SOQL Query

```
select id from DeployRequest
```

this would return an error saying

> sObject type 'DeployRequest' is not supported.

even if we use Tooling API Checkbox. So **DeployRequest** class is not available and it is not exposed.

DeployCallbackContext variable has jobId property with value 7074D000005dvGOQAY, which should be of type AsyncApexJob. However, if we try to query this record, no records will be returned

```
select id from AsyncApexJob where Id = '7074D000005dvGOQAY'
```

Comment: I defined the code to deploy metadata in a separate class but still calling `new MyClass().deploy()` results in deployment failing with the same `Required fields are missing: [MasterLabel]` error from anonymous window. Was there anything else you did differently?

Comment: I think we need to populate Label and Fullname attributes

Comment: Please make sure that you have line customMetadata.label = 'some label' working