# What is the proper way to enable SeeAllData when working with Event Monitoring Big Objects?

Tags: big-object, seealldata, event-monitoring

I'm using Event Monitoring & would like to use @SeAllData = true in my unit tests, so that I can leverage pre-existing logs.

However, when I enable it & query an Event Monitoring object, I end up getting a System.UnexpectedException.

Here is my unit test.

```
@isTest
public class Test_Logic {

@isTest (SeeAllData=true) static void TestLoginQuery(){
    DateTime StartDate = DateTime.now().addhours(-10000);
    DateTime EndDate = DateTime.now();

    List<SObject> sobjs = new List<SObject>();
    sobjs.addAll([SELECT EventIdentifier, EventDate, SourceIp, Browser, Platform, LoginUrl, HttpMethod, TlsProtocol, Status, PolicyOutcome 
                  FROM LoginEvent 
                  WHERE EventDate > :StartDate AND EventDate < :EndDate]);
   }
}
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
FATAL_ERROR System.UnexpectedException: common.exception.SfdcSqlException: We encountered an unexpected error. Contact Salesforce Customer Support. Error ID: 2095101290-105728 (-999027016)
```

Comment: I don't have enough experience with big object or event monitoring, but since you are getting a Salesforce gack, the error is not quite clear. If you're not getting any errors when you run the code with (SeeAllData=false), then I'm wondering if the query needs a limit. Otherwise, based on the documentation, I would assume that  the issue is that the query has two date comparison filters, and I'm not sure if that is supported. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.222.0.platform_events.meta/platform_events/sforce_api_objects_loginevent.htm

Answer (score 2):

**LoginEvent** is a big object that stores the event data of LoginEventStream. Accessing this object requires either the Salesforce Shield or Salesforce Event Monitoring add-on subscription and the View Data Leakage Detection Events user permission. Make sure you have those.

To query a big object you can use a subset of standard SOQL commands. You can use `<` and `>`, but only on the last field of your query. Any prior fields in your query can only use the `=` operator. In your example you are using two comparison operators.

As per the documentation example, try to use just one criteria in your query clause.

---

> LoginEvent allows filtering over two ordered fields: EventDate and EventIdentifier. There’s a catch here; your query doesn’t work unless you use the correct order and combination of these fields. The following list provides some examples of valid and invalid queries:
>
> You can filter solely on EventDate, but single filters on other fields fail. You can also use a comparison operator in this query type.

```
SELECT Application, Browser, EventDate, EventIdentifier, LoginUrl, UserId
FROM LoginEvent
WHERE EventDate <= 2014-11-27T14:54:16.000Z
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.222.0.platform_events.meta/platform_events/sforce_api_objects_loginevent.htm

---

If you want to test some code that uses the LoginEvent object you can also try to use the [JSON deserialization technique](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118391/unit-test-creating-custom-metadata/147994) in your test code.