# Scope of Validation Rule Formulas with Custom Metadata Types features

Tags: formula-field, customsetting, custom-metadata, release-notes

I am looking for solution to enable formula reading for Custom Setting List.I know that for Custom Setting Hierarchy we able to read it from formula.

The only work around is using trigger/apex to read custom setting list which I always think better I include the setting inside object instead of custom setting.

Recently in Salesforce Release: they enable feature [Employ Validation Rule Formulas with Custom Metadata Types (Pilot)](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_development_custom_metadata_validation_rule_formula.htm?edition=&impact=) which give me hope that this will be solution for custom setting list.

Unfortunately when I try, I am not able to implement it.

Scenario : to retrieve different email address for different business unit.

```
Business Unit ---> Email Address
Account Management -->ac@example.com
Business Dev -->businessdev@example.com
```

I created custom meta data named BusinessUnitEmail with field email .
So I inserted Custom Metadata Name and Email with corresponding value but when I try to retrieve I noticed that it bind value with API Name example

$CustomMetadata.BusinessUnitEmail__mdt.AccountManagement.Email , which already specify that this is email for AccountManagement instead of enable me to check if the business unit is 'Account Management'

Is this custom metadata feature only support feature like custom setting hierarchy but not custom setting list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be nominated to participate in a pilot program, contact your Salesforce.com account rep or Customer Support via help.salesforce.com.

Each nomination is evaluated individually, and orgs that are accepted into the program will be asked to sign a non-GA agreement.

Source: [Participate in a Salesforce Pilot](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000194013&language=en_US&type=1)

Answer (score 2):

I’m a dev on the team building the pilot. Nielsm is correct; you’ll need to contact support to be nominated to join the pilot program, as of Spring 18.

The feature only supports Custom Metadata Types. List Custom Settings will not be supported.

Custom Metadata Types have a lot of advantages over Custom Settings! Here’s question with more info about differences between the two: [What is the difference between Custom Settings and Custom Metadata Types](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/74049/what-is-the-difference-between-custom-settings-and-custom-metadata-types)